# Python Script that executes a Postgres SQL script, takes in response, and evaluates

Tags: python

I am looking to build a python script that can run a SQL script written in postgres, intake the responses, and evaluate them based on inputs.

Can someone give me a runthrough as to how they'd approach this?

Thanks

Comment: You should look into SQLAlchemy. It would provide you a good starting point

Comment: [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html) is also an option as well that could be a smaller learning curve than SQLAlchemy

Comment: `SQLAlchemy` lets you "a la carte" pick various features that you may or may not want to take off-the-shelf as part of your overall database interfacing solution. But it is not easy to learn, not at all. `Psycopg2` is the polar opposite, giving very little in the way of "extras". I believe SQLAlchemy actually uses `psycopg2` for its PostgreSQL connector.